# edit codes in php.ini in share hosting

Tags: php

Can anyone tell me how I can access to the php.ini file, when I use shared hosting ,, I tried to create a new php.ini to put on the root of website (because I just read depends on the server, maybe can override)

anyway, It didn't work for me,  how can I add some codes to php.ini while I don't have access to this file directly and I use share hosting.

Comment: why not talk to your shared host, the obvious experts on how their servers are set up

Comment: who count it down !!? if u have your solution just leave it ,, no need to express your problems in your life!

Comment: some random stranger clicked an arrow on you question, i think you will survive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put; you can't. In a shared hosting account, you do not have access to the **php.ini** file, because you are sharing the same system with millions of other users. 
 
   Use **.htaccess** or a **bootstrap** file instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you use PHP's [ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) function, you can set a lot of those settings in your code without touching php.ini, which most/all shared hosting accounts wouldn't let you touch.

Comment: Thanks Matt, 
I wanna enable PDO on the server 
    extension=php_pdo.dll

you mean the below code must work ?
    ini_set('extension','php_pdo.dll')

Comment: @Sali, unfortunately, adding an extension is not something you can do with ini_set. Like the other commenters have suggested, you'll want to get in touch with your host about that one.

Answer (score 1):

Most shared hosting company does NOT allow us to change the php.ini. Only some small hosting companies allow that. Ask your hosting for sure.

What exactly are you trying to do that needed you to change the php.ini?

If it's the longer execution time, you could get around with ajax / jquery. If it's redirect, use htaccess or php or javascript. If it's external file access, well, you need other high technique for that. :D

Comment: Actually , I have installed Drupal 7.17 in my laptop and it works, when I transferred it on the server the problem has been occurred.